# Parsing Json in powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I have an automation runbook in azure that receives a json string in a variable like so:

```
["value1","value2"]
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how to handle this variable and parse it.

```
$array = "'$jsonInput'"
$Services = $array | ConvertFrom-Json
switch($Services)
{
    value1 { $requested = $true ; break }
    Default { $requested = $false }
}
```

Using only single quotes does not resolve my input variable. Using `"'$jsonInput'"` does nothing and the variable `$requested` returns false. I believe this is because of the use of double quotes in the input variable. What is the correct way to parse this?

If I manually enter this when testing, it works.

```
$array = '["value1","value2"]'
```

But then again, not sure how to take this json string without quotes, append the quotes and resolve the variable.

Comment: `$array = "'$jsonInput'"` <- remove the single quotes (`'`) from this (it's already a string to PowerShell, no need to make it "extra stringy")

Comment: If `$jsonInput` looks as you show us you should be able to pipe it directly to `ConvertFrom-Json` without a need to use quotes

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen. That is what I started with. Then this happens:
```NotSpecified: Invalid array passed in, ',' expected. (16): ["value1" 
+ $Services = $array | ConvertFrom-Json ```

Comment: @NoobsCode sounds like `$jsonInput` doesn't actually contain the value you think it does... Can you show us how you obtain the json in the first place?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon resulted in the same error as above. bear in mind that this parameter is sent to PowerShell unquoted.

Comment: @NoobsCode You don't need quotes if the value stored in your variable _is already a string_ - the outer quotes of a string literal are entirely a _source-code concept_, the quotes don't actually get stored in memory

Comment: Can you show us what's actually in the $jsonInput variable? This string *["value1","value2"]* converted to json will look like this: *"[\"value1\",\"value2\"]"*

Comment: ["value1","value2"] is whats in the variable. So whats happening here is that I have a Microsoft Form with a multiple selection section. Using Power Automate I send the submitted form data to a runbook in azure. The Runbook is invoked with a parameter from where that json string is injected.